# Как вывести имя переменной?

Tags: python, if

Задание:

Даны три переменных.  Выведите ИМЯ переменной, которая имеет минимальное значение

```
first = 1
second = 2
third =3 
#Begin

#End
```

Мой код:

```
if first<second and second<third:
    if first<third:
        four = "first"
print (four)
```

Задание принято как неверно.
Как следовало вывести имя переменной?

Comment: Если предположить, что значения переменных не меняется, то вообще никакие условия не нужны - просто выводите "first". Если меняются, то у вас результат выведет только если произойдет вход в самый внутренний if, в остальных случаях будет ругаться на необъявленную переменную four.

Comment: Заголовок должен отражать задачу/проблему, а не непонятно что

Answer (score 2):

Найдите минимальное значение. Напечатайте имя какой-нибудь переменной, значение которой совпадает с минимумом:

```
min_value = min(first, second, third)
if first == min_value:
    print('first')
elif second == min_value:
    print('second')
else:
    print('third')
```

Comment: На случай если автор не знает как искать минимум : int[] a = {6,3,5,7,1,-8};
  int min = a[0];
  for(int i =0;i< a.length;i++){
   if(min > a[i] ) min = a[i];
  } . Это на java если что, но смысл я передал

Comment: Либо int min2 = (first > second? second : first);
int  min = min2 > third? third : min2;

Comment: Добрый день. Это практическое задание по оператору if. другие примеры система засчитает автоматически неверным ответом

Comment: Приведите пример, который мой код решит неправильно? Или что-то неправильно в самом коде?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно вывести минимальное значение при любых числах в first, second, third, как я полагаю, поэтому можно просто сделать так:

```
if first < second and first < third:
    print("First")
if second < first and second < third:
    print("Second")
if third< first and third < second:
    print("Third")
```

Если имя переменной будет другое, то можно вывести его так:

```
f'{Название Переменной=}'.split('=')[0]
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Спасибо вам за ответ. К сожалению, ответ приняло как неверный

Comment: Случай равенства потеряли. :(

Comment: Имена переменных начинаются со строчных букв.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу нестандартно:

```py
first = 1
second = 2
third = 3

*a, = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x[1], int), globals().items())
result, a = min(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(result)
```

Comment: Добрый день. Это практическое задание по оператору if. другие примеры система засчитает автоматически неверным ответом

Comment: @АнастасияИвкова, добрый. Но вы же не будете говорить что этот способ не работает? Я посчитал этот вопрос слишком простым, и решил ответить маленько по-другому.